# Specifying external Makefile options in Eclipse CDT

Tags: c++, eclipse, netbeans, makefile, eclipse-cdt

I'd like to (temporarily) migrate a C++ project from Netbeans to Eclipse (in order to use Eclipse's parallel debugger). So far I've created a "Makefile project with Existing Code" project in Eclipse that references the Netbeans project Makefile/directory. However the Netbeans project accepts config options for example

```
make -f Makefile CONF=GNU_Debug
```

How can I pass this option to the Makefile in Eclipse?

**Eclipse version**
Eclipse for Parallel Application Developers -- Mars.2 Release (4.5.2)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can change the default make call in the projects properties dialog:

[image]

My version:

> Version: Mars.1 Release (4.5.1)

---

Note that the `-f Makefile` should be superfluous.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to πάντα ῥεῖ's answer, which changes settings "globally" for a project, you can define individual make targets in the *Make Target* view.

Steps:

1. Choose *Window* -> *Show View* -> *Other...* -> *Make* -> *Make Target* (or simpler, press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>3</kbd> then type `Make Target` and choose the view from the list.)
2. Right click on the project in the view and choose *New...*
3. Enter the make target you want to use, e.g. `CONF=GNU_Debug` and press OK
4. Double-click on target to build

Here is a screenshot:

[image]

**Shortcuts**

- You can quickly rebuild last selected Make target by pressing <kbd>F9</kbd>
- Bring up a pop-up to select Make target by pressing <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F9</kbd>
- Access the same UI as above by right-clicking on project in *Project Explorer* and choosing *Make Targets* -> *Build* or selecting the same from the Project menu.