# How to do parallel make builds with -j in Eclipse CDT?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-cdt

From the command line, I can use `make -j16` to speed up compilation.

How to do that from Eclipse CDT?

Answer (score 1):

Right click on the project, then Properties, then C/C++.

Then you have two options:

- set the build command as shown at: [Specifying external Makefile options in Eclipse CDT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38412608/specifying-external-makefile-options-in-eclipse-cdt/38412667#38412667) , untick "Use default build command", and add `make -j16` there:

  [image]
- go to the "Behavior" tab and check "Enable parallel build". I wonder if this has any advantage other than using the total number of cores by default.

  [image]